# Need a precedent on a mySQL query WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a small search query for inventory. What I need is for the first WHERE clause to be absolute and the or clause to be secondary.

the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM inventory 
WHERE inv_body_style = 'TRUCK' 
  AND inv_make = 'MAZDA' 
   OR inv_make = 'FORD' 
ORDER BY inv_price, inv_make DESC
```

The issue I am having is that the query will also show the Mazda cars in the inveltory ... what I need is ONLY trucks (as that is the precedent condition).  I could accomplish it with javascript or php if I have to but I would rather run the complete query with accurate results in mySql ... thank for any help. Cheers

Comment: **Study [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) carefully !!!** then think what does your condition performs really. Then add needed parenthesis. Also study `IN` operator description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ONLY trucks of either brand (Mazda or Ford) use parenthesis in the search condition.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM inventory 
WHERE inv_body_style = 'TRUCK' 
  AND (inv_make = 'MAZDA' OR inv_make = 'FORD')
ORDER BY inv_price, inv_make DESC
```